# Remove part of string after "."

Tags: r, regex, string

I am working with NCBI Reference Sequence accession numbers like variable `a`:

```
a <- c("NM_020506.1","NM_020519.1","NM_001030297.2","NM_010281.2","NM_011419.3", "NM_053155.2")
```

To get information from the biomart package I need to remove the `.1`, `.2` etc. after the accession numbers. I normally do this with this code:

```
b <- sub("..*", "", a)

# [1] "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

But as you can see, this isn't the correct way for this variable. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You just need to escape the period:

```
a <- c("NM_020506.1","NM_020519.1","NM_001030297.2","NM_010281.2","NM_011419.3", "NM_053155.2")

gsub("\\..*","",a)
[1] "NM_020506"    "NM_020519"    "NM_001030297" "NM_010281"    "NM_011419"    "NM_053155"
```

Comment: Clarification: With functions in the base package (i.e. without other packages like `string r`), the options are as posted:
    b1 <- gsub("\\..*","",a, fixed=FALSE)
    b2 <- sub("\\..*","",a, fixed=FALSE)
In certain cases, you may need to change the `fixed` argument. However, here you *must* have it set to `FALSE` (which is the default); otherwise it won't work. Furthermore, you need the double escape `\\`, or you get an error.

Comment: You wouldn't use it with fixed as TRUE because we're using regular expression here.

Answer (score 18):

We can pretend they are filenames and remove *extensions*:

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext(a)
# [1] "NM_020506"    "NM_020519"    "NM_001030297" "NM_010281"    "NM_011419"    "NM_053155"
```

Answer (score 12):

You could do:

```
sub("*\\.[0-9]", "", a)
```

or

```
library(stringr)
str_sub(a, start=1, end=-3)
```

Comment: Alternatives: `str_replace(a,"\\.[0-9]","")` and `str_replace(a,"\\..*","")`

Comment: The `str_sub(a, start = 1, end = -3)` solution assumes that there are **only two characters** to remove (the "." and a single digit after it). For many gene ID systems, there could be multiple digits in the version (especially with probe IDs for instance). In this case, a more flexible solution would be `str_remove(a, pattern = "\\..*")`.

In the code above, the pattern is to find the first period (using `"\\."`), then *any* character after that (`"."`) *any* number of times (`"*"`).

Answer (score 11):

If the string should be of fixed length, then `substr` from `base R` can be used.  But, we can get the position of the `.` with `regexpr` and use that in `substr`

```
substr(a, 1, regexpr("\\.", a)-1)
#[1] "NM_020506"    "NM_020519"    "NM_001030297" "NM_010281"    "NM_011419"    "NM_053155"
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use a lookahead regex to extract the strings before `.`.

```r
library(stringr)

str_extract(a, ".*(?=\\.)")
[1] "NM_020506"    "NM_020519"    "NM_001030297" "NM_010281"   
[5] "NM_011419"    "NM_053155"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `str_split` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_split(a, "\\.", simplify=T)[,1]
```

```
[1] "NM_020506"    "NM_020519"    "NM_001030297" "NM_010281"    "NM_011419"    "NM_053155"
```