# R: Modify the values of a data frame according to different conditions applied to another table

Tags: r

I have a table like this one (table 1):

```
X   a   b   c   d
A   1   0   1   1
B   1   0   0   1
C   0   0   1   1
D   1   1   0   1
E   0   0   1   0
```

And another one with an identical column "X" like this one (table 2):

```
X   a    b       b.1    c     d     d.1
A   0.8  1.5     1.2    3     0.8   0.9
B   0.7  0.1     0.3    0.002 0.7   0.03
C   0.3  0.2     0.4    0.4   0.6   1.3
D   1.2  1.4     0.95   0.5   1.2   0.4
E   1    0.01    1.4    1.9   1.7   0.2
```

As you can see one column in table1 (e.g. column b) can have one or two corresponding columns in table2 (e.g. columns b and b.1)

I would like to apply the following modifications to table 1:

- If the value in table1 is 1 and in the corresponding columns from table2 at least one value is > 0.9, keep the value as a 1
- If the value in table1 is 1 but the corresponding value(s) in table2 are not > 0.9, replace with "NA"
- If the value in table1 is 0, but at least one corresponding value(s) in table2 is > 0.9, replace with "NA"
- If the value in table1 is 0, but the corresponding value(s) in table2 are not > 0.9, replace with 0

Therefore, I would get this table as a result:

```
X   a   b   c   d
A   NA  NA  1   NA
B   NA  0   0   NA
C   0   0   NA  1
D   1   1   0   1
E   NA  NA  1   NA
```

Please let me know if I can clarify anything further. Thank you for your help!

Please note that the solution has to be applicable to much larger data frames!

Here is the example data:

```
> dput(table1)
structure(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E"), c("a", "b", "c", "d")))

> dput(table2)
structure(c(0.8, 0.7, 0.3, 1.2, 1, 1.5, 0.1, 0.2, 1.4, 0.01, 
1.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.95, 1.4, 3, 0.002, 0.4, 0.5, 1.9, 0.8, 0.7, 
0.6, 1.2, 1.7, 0.9, 0.03, 1.3, 0.4, 0.2), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(
    c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), c("a", "b", "b.1", "c", "d", 
    "d.1")))
```

Comment: Can you please make your example reproducible?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Do you mean provide the data for the tables?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution requires converting the matrices to data frames and using functions from `tidyverse`. There is a definitely simpler way to do this. Hopefully, someone can share their answers.

```
# Create example data 
dt1 <- structure(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                   1, 1, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", 
                                                                  "D", "E"), c("a", "b", "c", "d")))

dt2 <- structure(c(0.8, 0.7, 0.3, 1.2, 1, 1.5, 0.1, 0.2, 1.4, 0.01, 
                   1.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.95, 1.4, 3, 0.002, 0.4, 0.5, 1.9, 0.8, 0.7, 
                   0.6, 1.2, 1.7, 0.9, 0.03, 1.3, 0.4, 0.2), .Dim = 5:6, .Dimnames = list(
                     c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), c("a", "b", "b.1", "c", "d", 
                                                   "d.1")))

# Load package
library(tidyverse)

# Extract row names
Row <- rownames(dt1)

# Convert dt1 and dt2 to data frames
dt1 <- as_data_frame(dt1)
dt2 <- as_data_frame(dt2)

# Add the row names as a new column
dt1 <- dt1 %>% mutate(Row = Row)
dt2 <- dt2 %>% mutate(Row = Row)

# Re-organize the dataset
dt1_r <- dt1 %>% gather(Class, Value, -Row)
dt2_r <- dt2 %>% gather(Class, Value, -Row)

# Keep only the letters, remove numbers and . in Class
dt2_r <- dt2_r %>% mutate(Class = gsub("\\..*", "", Class))

# Check the value in dt2 for each combination of Row and Class
# if any value is larger than 0.9, mark as 1, otherwise 0
dt3 <- dt2_r %>%
  group_by(Row, Class) %>%
  summarise(Threshold = ifelse(any(Value > 0.9), 1, 0))

# Merge dt3 and dt1_r by Row and Class
dt4 <- dt1_r %>% left_join(dt3, by = c("Row", "Class"))

# Create a new column to document the result based on the condition in Value and Threshold
dt5 <- dt4 %>%
  group_by(Row, Class) %>%
  mutate(Value2 = ifelse(Value == 1 & Threshold == 1, 1,
                         ifelse(Value == 1 & Threshold != 1, NA,
                                ifelse(Value == 0 & Threshold == 1, NA, 0)))) %>%
  select(Row, Class, Value2)

# Re-organize dt5
dt5_r <- dt5 %>% spread(Class, Value2)

# Convert dt5_r to a matrix
dt6 <- dt5_r %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Row) %>%
  as.matrix()

# Rename the matrix, dt6 is the final output
rownames(dt6) <- Row
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this has to be applicable to much larger data frames, so giving lists of row names is not really an option.

Comment: @arielle Please see my update. We can use `rownames(dt1)` to extract the row names, so we don't have to use list of row names. By the way, the row names is in your example dataset, if you do not want to use row names, please start a new question with modified dataset

Comment: @arielle Notice that row name here is just an identifier. We can also use numeric ID `(1:nrow(dt))` for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, that is fine, the row names can be used, thanks for your comments. Another thing is that the column names might contain numbers, for example a2b, 3ae4 and 3ae4.1, instead of a, b and b.1. Would it be possible to make your code applicable to this situation please?

Comment: @arielle Number is not an issue. `gsub("[0-9 & //.]", "", Class)` is designed to remove numbers and the dot. However, other letters are an issue. It is not clear how to do grouping based on your updated example. For instance, should `a2b` be grouped with `a` or `b`? Without clear rules, it is impossible to develop solutions.

Comment: I apologize if this is confusing. Here is what I meant: The column names can have any identifier, followed by ".1" or not. They should be grouped by the whole identifier (which is before the dot), which can contain letters, number and symbols. To extend on my last example, we could have column names like this:  "a-2b", "3ae-4" and "3ae-4.1". Then 3ae-4 and 3ae-4.1 should be grouped. I hope this clarifies things. Please do let me know otherwise and thanks again for your help!

Comment: @arielle Thanks for the clarification. I believe we can design a regular expression to remove everything after the dot. For example, `3ae-4.1` will be `3ae-4`. After that, grouping will be feasible. Here seems to be a relevant thread for this work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617702/remove-part-of-string-after

Comment: @arielle I have updated the `gsub` command to be `gsub("\\..*", "", Class)`. This should be more flexible than my original approach.

Comment: Yes that makes sense! Thank you! It seems to be working