# Make new column that contains part of expression in another column

Tags: r

I have a data frame like so:

```
 before<- data.frame( Var1= 
  c("174_1","174_1","174_2","174_3","175_1","175_1"))
```

I would like to add another column `Var2` that contains the part of the expression in `Var1` before the underscore. The new column would appear as follows:

```
after<- data.frame( Var1= 
  c("174_1","174_1","174_2","174_3","175_1","175_1"), Var2= 
  c("174","174","174","174","175","175"))
```

I am believe functions like grepl() could be useful for this, however, I do not know how to specify keeping part of an before the grepl("_").

Comment: Either this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617702/remove-part-of-string-after - or one of the linked duplicates should solve your issue.

Comment: `sub("_[^_]", "", before$Var1)`

Comment: `transform(before,var2=sub("_.*","",Var1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1$b <- substr(df1$a, 1, regexpr('_', df1$a)[1]-1)
```

This takes a substring of everything up until the underscore

Comment: `substr` and `regexpr` are vectorised, so you can just do: `substr(before$Var1, 1, regexpr('_', before$Var1)[1]-1)`

Comment: And if I wanted every thing after the underscore how would that look?

Comment: @Danielle Two changes - add to the index of the search result rather than subtract from it, And use the regex result as the lower bound of the substring rather than the upper. The following should work: `substr(df1$a,regexpr('_', df1$a)[1]+1,nchar(as.character(df1$a)))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `tidyr::separate`:

```
d = data.frame(Var1 = c("174_1","174_1","174_2","174_3","175_1","175_1"))
temp = tidyr::separate(d, Var1, into=c("v1", "v2"), sep="_")
temp
   v1 v2
1 174  1
2 174  1
3 174  2
4 174  3
5 175  1
6 175  1
d[["Var2"]] <- temp[["v1"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
before <- data.frame(Var1= c("174_1","174_1","174_2","174_3","175_1","175_1"))

after <- data.frame(Var1 = before$Var1,Var2 = unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(before$Var1), '_'), `[[`,1)))
```