# How can I drop decimal values in a specific column in R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe shown below (df <- read_csv("~/data.csv"):

```
gene_id         a       b
abc100.12       30      70
abc101.23       40      80
abc102.345      50      90
abc103.4567     60      100
```

I want to make change this dataframe like below:

```
gene_id         a        b
abc100         30        70
abc101         40        80
abc102         50        90
abc103         60        100
```

Basically, I want to drop decimal values in gene_id column and keep everything else the same.
If the original dataframe is df (`df <- read_csv("~/data.csv")`),
how can I write a R code so that I have a dataframe shown above?

Comment: `dat$gene_id <- gsub(\\.*$, "", dat$gene_id)`.

Comment: `df$gene_id <- sub("[.].*", "", df$gene_id)`

Comment: Fixing my typo `dat$gene_id <- gsub(\\..*$, "", dat$gene_id)`.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617702/remove-part-of-string-after and others.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script to replace the values after decimal with blank:

```
rownames(df) <- gsub("\\..*", "", rownames(df))
```

if the gene_id is assigned to row names.

Comment: You’re assigning that to colnames?

Comment: The data was in raw format, not tabular, and it seemed to me that the values are column names. The question is now edited. I corrected my answer to reflect the change. Thank you for the note!