# How to change row and column names based on values in another data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a matrix, `mx`, with named rows and columns, with hundreds of rows/columns. A sample looks like:

```
   ABC DEF GHI
ABC 1   0   1
DEF 0   1   0
GHI 0   0   1
```

And suppose I have a data frame called `df` with two columns which looks like:

```
letters country
ABC     UK
DEF     USA
GHI     Egypt
```

I want to rename the rows and columns in `mx` based on the corresponding `country` values in `df`.

I.e. I would like `mx` to become:

```
      UK USA Egypt
UK    1   0   1
USA   0   1   0
Egypt 0   0   1
```

Does anyone know whether this is possible in R?

Answer (score 2):

You may try

```
x <- colnames(mx) # = rownames(mx)
df$country[match(x, df$letters)]
colnames(mx) <- df$country[match(x, df$letters)]
#rownames(mx) <- df$country[match(x, df$letters)]
```

Comment: The logic is the same, but you could even do both `dimnames` in one go - `dimnames(mx) <- lapply(dimnames(mx), \(x) df$country[match(x, df$letters)] )`

Comment: Thanks! This works but now the row names save like `USA.1`, `USA.2` etc. where I have repeats. Is there a way to remove '.' and numbers from the row names?

Comment: @HelpMe Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617702/remove-part-of-string-after